# How to convert Array with N items into array with N objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Let's say we have an array like this one:

```
const arr = [2,3,'red', 'white', ...]; // With n items
```

I would like to push that array into an array with objects inside like the this:

```
[{a:2, b:3, c:'red', d:'white'}, {a: ..., b: ..., c: ...}, ...}
```

I'm getting the data from a CSV file which gives me just an array. I need to assign that values into an object with 13 properties each one, so each object will looks like:

```
{ a: ..., b: ..., c: ..., d: ..., e: ..., f: ..., g: ...,
  h: ..., i: ..., j: ...., k: ..., l: ..., m: ... }, ...
```

I broke my brain trying to make this operation as simple as possible but I need help guys.

Comment: What do you mean by "push into an array with objects inside"? Could you be a little more clear what the function should do?

Comment: why is c 'white'? where does 'red' go?

Comment: @PetarPetrovic Just random values Petar.

Comment: @DerekBrown function must convert [1,2,3, ...] in [{a:1, ...}, ...];

Comment: `I broke my brain trying` - doesn't look like you've actually tried anything at all

Comment: Seems an easy algorithm but it's tricky. You can believe me or not. Anyway Stack Overflow it's the perfect site to discuss this kind of problems.

Comment: Problem is not well-defined. "Make for me something smart"

Comment: @MBo Pranav C Balan has the correct approach.

Comment: Perhaps he knows telepathy ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using nested for loops.

```js
const arr = [2, 3, 'red', 'white', 'ss', 3, 'red', 'white', 'ss', 3, 'red', 'white', 'ss', 3, 'red', 'white', 'ss', 3, 'red', 'white', 'ss', 3, 'red', 'white', 'ss', 3, 'red', 'white', 'ss', 3, 'red', 'white', 'ss', 3, 'red', 'white', 'ss', 3, 'red', 'white', 'ss', 3, 'red', 'white', 'ss', 3, 'red', 'white', 'ss', 3, 'red', 'white', 'ss', 3, 'red', 'white', 'ss', 3, 'red', 'white', 'ss', 3, 'red', 'white', 'ss', 3, 'red', 'white', 'ss', 3, 'red', 'white', 'ss'];

// array for storing result
var res = [];

// iterate over each 13 elements from the array
for (var i = 0, i1 = 0; i < arr.length; i += 13, i1++) {
  // define object
  res[i1] = {};

  // iterate over 13 properties a to m
  for (var j = 0; i + j < arr.length && j < 13; j++) {
    // define the property, property can be generate 
    // using radix 36(which includes 0 to 9  and a to z)
    // where a to m is within ( 10 to 22 )
    res[i1][(j + 10).toString(36)] = arr[i + j];
  }
}


console.log(res);
```

Comment: `(index+10).toString(36)` - nice

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid nested loops:

```
const arr = [2, 3, 'red', 'white', 'ss', 3, 'red', 'white', 'ss', 3, 'red', 'white', 'ss', 3, 'red', 'white', 'ss', 3, 'red', 'white', 'ss', 3, 'red', 'white', 'ss', 3, 'red', 'white', 'ss', 3, 'red', 'white', 'ss', 3, 'red', 'white', 'ss', 3, 'red', 'white', 'ss', 3, 'red', 'white', 'ss', 3, 'red', 'white', 'ss', 3, 'red', 'white', 'ss', 3, 'red', 'white', 'ss', 3, 'red', 'white', 'ss', 3, 'red', 'white', 'ss', 3, 'red', 'white', 'ss', 3, 'red', 'white', 'ss'];

resultArray = [];
tempObject = [];

for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // Get a letter to use as a key
    newKey = String.fromCharCode(97 + (i % 26));

    // Push that onto the object
    temp_obj[newKey] = arr[i];

    // If you've done 13, put that into the array
    if((i + 1) % 13 == 0) {
        res_array.push(temp_obj);
        temp_obj = {};
    }
}
```